# How to get last Get Last 7 entries

Tags: mysql, database

How can I get the last 7 records from work_hours table.

Here you see my own query. what will be change in this?

```
try{

    String query="SELECT * FROM work_hours";

    ResultSet rs =db.Select(query);

    while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name
        int ID  = rs.getInt("ID");
        String Date=rs.getString("Date");
        int Start_Time = rs.getInt("Start_Time");
        int End_Time=rs.getInt("End_Time");
        float Over_Time=rs.getFloat("Over_Time");
        int Advance=rs.getInt("Advance");
        int Other=rs.getInt("Other");
    }

}catch(SQLException se){
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what does your query produce? an error? or wrong records? generally we use a limit 7 at the end of a query to set the number of records we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String query = "
               SELECT * FROM work_hours
               ORDER BY ID DESC
               LIMIT 7 
               ";
```

The above query will fetch the last 7 entries from your DB. Hope this is helpful to you!.